# How to fix slow api response in IE in reactjs using cross-fetch?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, api

I have some apis which give very slow response in internet explore. I am fetching apis using cross-fetch in reactjs.

I have tried

**1) Cache Buster in my request.
var myRequestURL = '/get/somefunction?buster='+new Date().getTime();**

**2) By adding header cache-control.
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache,no-store")**

**3) By adding header
Pragma: "no-cache"**

```
import fetch from "cross-fetch";

const { Promise } = require("es6-promise");

const API_URL = "API URL";
export default (endpoint, method = "get", body) =>
  fetch(`${API_URL}${endpoint}`, {
    headers: { Pragma: "no-cache" },
    method,
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
  })
    .then(response => response.json().then(json => ({ json, response })))
    .then(({ json, response }) => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        return Promise.reject(json);
      }
      return json;
    })
    .then(response => response, error => error);
```

I am expecting fast response in IE like chrome browser.

Comment: Ever found a solution for this?